# Spend Action Points to activate Dragonmark?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron

I could swear I remember a rule—whether default, or part of a feat or class feature, or something—that allowed you to cast your spell-like ability using an action point instead of its typical daily use. But now I can’t find anything like that.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Not looking for shenanigans, just something that allows this functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be thinking of the Unlock Dragonmark feat (*Dragonmarked*, p. 144), which provides the following benefit:

> You can spend 1 action point to use any spell-like ability granted by your dragonmark or its lesser versions as a standard action, even if you do not normally have access to those abilities.